# How to automatically update Targets for an Ant build via Eclipse with new run configurations

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit, targets

We are creating some JUnit tests as part of QA development. So we are doing this daily and while running individual tests, or part of a package, they do appear under the Run arrow:

[image: latest run files]

they do not appear in the Ant build Targets:

[image: Ant targets]

Well.. you can see that the Schedules_Load appears but that's because I have exported the Ant build again.

Note that even if I create Run configurations using the Eclipse menu:

[image: run config]

It still doesn't update my Ant Targets list..

Under the menu item Project I do have Build automatically checked but don't think it makes any difference anyway, just thought I would mention it.

So is there any way to automatically update Ant targets with new run configurations without having to export the Ant build again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try selecting the check-box: *"Refresh automatically"*.

```
 Window->Preferences->General->Workspace->"Refresh automatically"
```

[image: GUI]
<sub>(source: [avajava.com](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/eclipse/how-do-i-automatically-refresh-the-projects-in-my-workspace/how-do-i-automatically-refresh-the-projects-in-my-workspace-01.gif))</sub>

Comment: I don't have a Refresh automatically checkbox in Eclipse Kepler, at least it's not under Workspace. But refreshing the project does not update the target list.

Comment: can you any of the following, in preferences>general>workspace: `refresh on access, build automatically, refresh using native hooks or polling` ?

Comment: also, do close and open eclipse once. and, can you see your targets in `Ant view` ?

Comment: I did restart Eclipse, I have the same view for Ant Targets as the image that I posted earlier. The new run configs are not there.